# JAXB - How to add xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB to create XML file from a result set.

I have created java/ /class files using the xsd with the help of xjc utiliy. Now I am trying to create the xml file using the Marshaller. In the XML file I do not see the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` attribute with the root tag.

```
public class JAXBConstructor
 {  
  public void generateXMLDocument(File xmlDocument){
   try 
      {
         JAXBContext  jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com");                 
         Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();    
         marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true); 
         marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
         com.ObjectFactory factory = new com.ObjectFactory();
         USERTASKSImpl  userTasks =(USERTASKSImpl)(factory.createUSERTASKS());         
         USERTASKTypeImpl userTaskType = (USERTASKTypeImpl)(factory.createUSERTASKSTypeUSERTASKType());         
         userTaskType.setName("zmannan");
         userTaskType.setCode("G5023920");
         java.util.List userTaskList=userTasks.getUSERTASK();         
         userTaskList.add(userTaskType);         
         marshaller.marshal(userTasks, new FileOutputStream("User_Task.xml"));
}
```

Output of the code : This does not contain the XMLSchema value -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<USER_TASKS xmlns="http://schemas.jpmchase.net/Recertification">
    <USER_TASK>
        <Code>G5023920</Code>
        <Name>zmannan</Name>
    </USER_TASK>
</USER_TASKS>
```

Please help how can I add the schema-instance value in the root tag.

Comment: The namespace is not in the output because there's no need for it. Why do you want it there?

Comment: @skaffman - I see this in xsd but not in XML file created. I sent this xml to other application and they validate it against the same xsd. It may create problems for them.

Comment: The `xsi` schema is only required on the schema document, not the XML documents themselves. It should cause them no problems.

Comment: @skaffman : The issue is resolved by adding JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION to the marshaller. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Anurag: as a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: Actually, XML instances sometimes need to be `xsi:` things. But I DO agree with @skaffman in this case. You compiled the xsd and marshalled with the Java class that xjc produced. Then you're are ok to go. You don't have to specify any unnecessary `<xsi:` directs event if schema validation is expected.